# Execute MySQL LIMIT in a JPQL sub query

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have following threee tables which needs to be left join to retrieve details.

**Table A**

messageId | senderName

**Table B**

messageId | content

**Table C**

messageId | eventTime | status

Table A and Table B has a one to one relationship and Table A and Table C has a one to many relationship. 
I need to create a left join on all 3 tables to retrieve values on all the tables with latest status from Table C

message id will be in the tables as below

[image]

I have created following JPQL query that I can use to retrieve all three entities.

```
select d, e, s from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.messageId = b.messageId
left join TableC c on a.messageId = c.messageId
and c.status = (select st.status from TableC st where st.messageId = a.messageId order by st.eventTime DESC limit 1)
```

But due to limit I have used in query I'm not able to run as a JPQL query.
Is there any way that I can format this query to run as a JPQL query? (except native query in JPA)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not actually limit the results of a subquery in JPQL. Best bet would probably be to create a view that will execute your subquery, or in your case even the whole query and then selecting from the view.